# Angular double interpolation in template

Tags: angular, interpolation, angular-template

Having a collection that you iterate through, is there a way to use a property of
the elements from the collection and use it as a key to take some else, from another stream (like a double interpolation) ? Just from the template alone.

Something like:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let book of (books$ | async)">
     <td> {{ (text$ | async)[{{ book.title }}] }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Where I could use `book.title` to take something from text.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a pipe which take the book.title as parameter and searches for the text in the app store.